How to fix node-only dependencies in In Angular 17 and 18?
From my understanding, Angular uses Vite and EsBuild. When searching for how to polyfill node-only dependencies, most of the results are about the old browser compatibility. The rest are for older versions of angular.
What is the V17 (and V18) way of polyfilling node dependencies, like stream?
Is there a way to use vite-plugin-node-polyfills to polyfill anything we need?

You don't need to polyfill any node dependencies. Just keep NodeJS version aligned with Angular's compatibility table https://v17.angular.io/guide/versions. You also have "polyfills" array in the angular.json where you can put any extra scripts you need for the app

When we add a library that's not built for browser, we get errors. In react, it's really simple to get rid of these errors, but in angular I've not been lucky

You can probably use that "vite-plugin-node-polyfills" as it will probably fit well with vite.
But for esbuild there's a good one called "esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node" and you can find it here: https://npm.io/package/esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node

How to set it up properly, so that it works in both development (npm run dev) and production?

@Alireza If you are using Vite, in the url you shared above it's documented how to use it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills

Vite provides a way to polyfill node-specific modules using plugins like vite-plugin-node-polyfills. This plugin allows you to specify which node modules should be polyfilled when building for the browser environment.
You can install it with the command


npm install vite-plugin-node-polyfills --save-dev



Rest of the steps you need to follow from the documentation of this library itself i.e https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills

The Vite plugin vite-plugin-node-polyfills, you suggest you can indeed polyfill Node.js dependencies. Below I will provide you some details on how to configure it.

Install the Vite plugin

npm install vite vite-plugin-node-polyfills


Configure the Vite
You should configure vite.config.ts as bellow.

To configure polyfills in my example I use the plugin you provided vite-plugin-node-polyfills. Also I decided to use NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin and NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin to ensure that the node modules and globals will be polyfilled correctly in the build.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import angular from '@analogjs/vite-plugin-angular'; // <- change it with your angular plugin
import NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';
import nodePolyfills from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    angular(),
    nodePolyfills({
      globals: true,
      buffer: true,
      process: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      example: 'example-node-plugin',
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
          process: true,
        }),
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
    },
  },
});

in the alias describe all the node modules you want to polyfill
resolve: {
  alias: {
    example: 'example-node-plugin',
  },
},


Update your running scripts
Open package.json and update it as follow:

{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  }
}

I use the following vite scripts to run dev environment by npm run start. To test prod build I use npm run build and after the build command npm run serve to serve the production build.
It depends on your angular project configuration but you can adjust it by your needs. But the code above should help initially.
Resources

Angular, Analog, and Vite
Vite Build
@esbuild-plugins

